# How can I alter the ieeetr bib style to add brackets to the year?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I'm trying to change the bibliography from this:

```
[40] B. Jeziorski and H. Monkhorst, “Coupled-cluster method for   
multideterminantal reference states,” Physical Review A, vol. 24, 
no. 4, p. 1668, 1981.
```

to this

```
[40] B. Jeziorski and H. Monkhorst, “Coupled-cluster method for 
multideterminantal reference states,” Physical Review A, vol. 24, 
no. 4, p. 1668, (1981).
```

with brackets around the year. Currently I'm using the plain vanilla `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: @Guido Thanks, blame my style on naivety. but i'll catch up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify the function `format.date`, in  particular the two lines after `month empty$` have to modified to insert the parenthesis.  Please, change the name of the file after you modified it (i.e., `myieeetr.bst` and use `\bibliographystyle{myieeetr}` instead)

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year empty$
    { month empty$
        { "" }
        { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$
          month
        }
      if$
    }
    { month empty$
        { "(" year * ")" * } 
        { "(" month * " " * year * ")" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Comment: thats it, it worked