# Change ieetr bibliography style to last name first

Tags: bibtex, natbib, ieee-style

I'm using the `ieeetr` bibliography style for my references and I'm getting initials then last name, how would I change this to last name first?

Here is what it looks like at the moment:

> `[1]` X. Chen, H. Niu, D. Li, and Y. Li, “Intrinsic correlation between hardness and
>       elasticity in polycrystalline materials and bulk metallic glasses,” arXiv preprint
>       arXiv:1102.4063, (2011).

and this is what I'd like to have:

> `[1]` Chen X., Niu H., Li D., and Li Y., “Intrinsic correlation between hardness and
>       elasticity in polycrystalline materials and bulk metallic glasses,” arXiv preprint
>       arXiv:1102.4063, (2011).

How would I do that? I'm currently using the `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` with a slight modification according to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80479/how-can-i-alter-the-ieeetr-bib-style-to-add-brackets-to-the-year).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you've obtained the file `ieeetr.bst` from a site such as http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/biblio/bibtex/base/, you could make a copy of this file (naming it, e.g., `myieeetr.bst`) and make the following edits to the newly copied file:

1. In the function `format.names`, locate the following line (l. 214 in my copy of the file)

   ```
   { s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
   ```

   and change it to

   ```
   { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll,}{ jj,}{ f.}" format.name$ 't :=
   ```

   *Note*: If you do *not* want a comma between the surname and the first name(s) (unless there's a "junior" part to the author's name), change `{ll,}{ jj,}` to `{ll}{, jj,}` in the string given above.
2. *Optional*: In the function `format.crossref.editor` (l. 518 in my copy of the file), change the line

   ```
       { editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
   ```

   to

   ```
       { editor #2 "{vv~}{ll, }{jj, }{f.}" format.name$ "others" =
   ```
3. Save the modified file (repeat: use a filename that's *different* from `ieeetr.bst`), either in the directory where your main `.tex` file is located or somewhere in the search path of your TeX distribution. Then, start invoking it with the statement `\bibliographystyle{myieeetr}`.

Comment: fantastic. would vote up but im > 15 rep :(

Comment: though you may want that to be  {vv~}{ll }{jj, }{f.}  (without the comma) sine it produces:   "Chen, X., Niu, H., Li, D"

Comment: @mike-m - Noted. Please see the "Note" paragraph at the end of bullet point #1. I guess it may be preferable to have a comma both before and after the "junior" part of a person's full name.