# Change the ordering of names of bibliographic entries to "Surname, Name" format

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I use the very popular [Easy Thesis](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/easy-thesis) template with very common standard packages and only slight adaptions, like `natbib` (see below). Everything works smoothly, aside one small issue, the Bibliography writes the Name, Surname format.

It seems to be a popular problem, and [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102597/change-ieetr-bibliography-style-to-last-name-first) offered a solution to same kind, but I cannot reproduce it. Where should I change the format, or even is there a better way. I'm fearing any massive changes, because I cannot overview them. However, I will try any proposal, since I'm stuck. Thank You!

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[UKenglish, USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[threshold=2]{csquotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{0.08em}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[authoryear, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}
```

Comment: The formatting of the bibliographic entries is controlled by the bibliography style in use, i.e., the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` command. Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: @Mico Thank you. `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` I think?!

Comment: May I suggest you take a look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131100/5001)? It deals specifically with the `plainnat` case. As it appears that you do *not* want to abbreviate the first names down to their initials, be sure to use `{ s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, ff}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=`  rather than `{ s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=` as the replacement string. After creating the new bibliography style file, be sure to refer to it in the `\bibliographystyle` command *and* to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to propagate all changes.

Comment: Thank you much, you put much work in your answers. Compliment! I cannot find the required file at all. The university regulations don't say much about how to format them, but they suggest to use ISO 690-2 format http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_690 . Is there a possibility to overwrite the actual setting with some correspondent BibTex ISO?

Comment: @Mico is it OK for you if i change the Title to: "How to change natbib-BibTex Bibliography to “Surname, Name” according to ISO-690-2 format?"

Comment: You can change the title of your posting any which way you want. :-) Note that ISO 690 (a) leaves it up to the author to decide whether first names should be abbreviated or not and (b) deals with many more issues than just the formatting of authors' names. To find the file, can you open a command window and type "kpsewhich plainnat.bst"?  If you can't find the file on your computer's hard drive, you can also get it [from the CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/plainnat.bst).

Comment: @Mico Thank you. I did not find it again. However, can you please get a short answer, so I can accept it. .. I asked for the title because you might already worked for a written answer, so it may not be actual anymore. Wish you best :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using BibTeX, the formatting of the bibliographic entries -- including the ordering of first and last names -- is determined by the settings contained in the bibliography style file that's in use. It would appear that you're using the `plainnat` style file. Fortunately, it's not difficult to modify the settings in `plainnat.bst` that govern the ordering of first and last names.

- Find the file `plainnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. (One way to find this file is to issue the command `kpsewhich plainnat.bst` at a command prompt; this should provide you with the needed information. If you can't find the file on your computer's hard drive, you can always obtain it [from the CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/plainnat.bst).) Copy this file to, say `myplainnat.bst`; don't edit directly a file provided as part of your TeX distribution.
- Open the file `myplainnat.bst` in your favorite text editor and search for function named `format.names`. (It starts on line 216 in my copy of `plainnat.bst`.)
- In this function, look for the line

  ```
  { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  Change this line to

  ```
  { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, ff}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```
- Save the file `myplainnat.bst` either to the directory that contains your main `.tex` file or to a directory that's searched by your BibTeX distribution. (If you choose the second option, depending on your TeX distribution, you may also have to refresh the filename database of the TeX distribution.)
- Start using the modified bibliography style file by issuing the command `\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}`, and be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more on the main `.tex` file to propagate all changes.