# How to use ISO-690-2 format for BibTex?

Tags: bibtex

For a thesis (template [Easy Thesis](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/easy-thesis/)) it is required to use [ISO 690-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_690). I would like to use it in connection with `BibTex`. Is there a package, setting or extension to do this? I use English language, so it is no need for special adaptions. Thank you :)

Comment: I found https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690 for `biblatex`. Others say the style `plainnat` is close. A `grep -R 690 *` command in my `texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst` returned 11 results.

Comment: Thank you :) Can you please tell a inexperienced Windows7 user what to do?

Comment: I'm not sure where those files would be (how did you install TeX?), but if you do a search for `*.bst` you should find them. The directory name should also still be `bibtex/bst`. I'm going to post an answer listing all the ones I found, so it is easier to see.

Comment: I've looked at the innards of the ISO 690-2 specification, and they look more like broad guidelines to me. I.e., they leave a lot of details -- such as whether or not authors' first names should be abbreviated, whether or not journal names should be set in italics, etc. unspecified. There must therefore be lots and lots of bibliography style files that are compatible with this standard; a style file proclaiming that it adheres to the standard is a sufficient, but not a necessary, criterion.

Comment: I am the author of mentioned biblatex style and it follows Czech version of ISO 690, which is pretty strict in using of various elements, I don't know whether it is compatible with your guidelines

Comment: @michal.h21 Thank you :) I'm writing on English. I found your page on GitHub, but don't know how to add (which file should I download from GitHub and copy where), and set the standard (read in the README file that cs_CZ is set, which is the correspondent for English). Sorry, I'm a bit cautious because I want to avoid to have problems with the whole thesis. Thank you, anyway, for direct help and for the implementation :)

Comment: @Mico Thank you again. So I interpret now that this `.bst` file is in the LaTex folder (not the document folder)? I'm now on another PC. but I try in cca. 1h. .. and answer.

Comment: @alex English is default, so you don't need to set sortlocale variable. it is en_US for US English, in the case if you really need it

Comment: @michal.h21 So I tried and had a lot of errors. I followed the README-file. so I may do something wrong. Q: see here are all packages I actually used before adding `biblatex` http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168172/change-the-ordering-of-names-of-bibliographic-entries-to-surname-name-format do I have to stop some. Second, do I have to block something inside the template (you find the template download link above)? Thank you

Comment: @alex you must comment out `\usepackage[...]{natbib}` it is incompatible with biblatex. I also found some small problem with my code, you should download new version

Comment: @michal.h21 I'm sorry, `natbib` is requred for the references in text in "harvard style". Thank you for your friendly help and good luck!

Comment: @alex iso-authoryear also support references in text in 'harvard style' :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my installation, the following `bst` files mention ISO 690-2:

```
abntex2-num.bst
abbrvhtml.bst
alphahtml.bst
plainhtml.bst
unsrthtml.bst
en-mtc.bst
fr-mtc.bst
sapthesis.bst
abbrvurl.bst
alphaurl.bst
plainurl.bst
unsrturl.bst
```

You could try each one and see if it is what you want. Searching for those filenames should find them, I see that they may all simply contain a "Webpage entry type" that you could copy into whatever file you're currently using.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Cannot check now. I answer ASAP when I'm back at the PC (cca. 1h).