# Finding citation style from journal paper

Tags: bibtex, citing

How to find citation style from this journal citation format ? I need following format in paper.
[image: Journal Citation format]

I downloaded jabref and included bib file in latex with bibliography style

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

But couldn't get as mentioned in picture. 
Can I get an idea how to write in such format as in picture in latex?

Comment: Do you use `bibtex` or `biblatex`?

Comment: I use Bibtex ..

Comment: That wasn't fast enough! Well wait a little I may modify the answer to using bibtex.

Comment: You are good to go! (Check the edit of the answer)

Comment: Before you go into meticulously trying to replicate the journal style, double check if the journal has a submission template available that includes a bibliography style or at least instructions on how the bibliography should be prepared in LaTeX. Some journals ship their own BibTeX `.bst` styles, some accept bibliographies produced by BibTeX styles that do not completely match their in-house style since the bibliography is reformatted later in the submission process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are going `biblatex` (from your keywords tag) to manage your reference, and seeing you would like the references to be sorted numerically, with the family name first and the given name initials second (`\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}`), then you can get something like this:

[image]

The code of which:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, giveninits=true, style=ieee]{biblatex} % using biblatex with style style=ieee for sorting ref by numbering
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} % Print family name first
\addbibresource{reference.bib} % the file inside which references are stored 
\usepackage[hidelinks, colorlinks=true]{hyperref} % OPTIONAL
%
\begin{document}
%
\section{Introduction} \label{sec:intro}
In order to cite one reference, you can use cite command like this \cite{Doe_2020}. You can also cite two references like this \cite{Doe_2020,Tenis_2000}.
%
\printbibliography % list of references is printed here
\end{document}
```

The contents of reference.bib file is (added at the same main directory of `main.tex`)

```
@Book{Doe_2020,
  author    = {John Doe},
  publisher = {John Wiley},
  title     = {Differential equations : an introduction to modern methods and applications},
  year      = {2020},
  address   = {New Jersey},
  isbn      = {9780471651413},
  keywords  = {Differential equations},
  language  = {In English},
}

@Article{Tenis_2000,
  author  = {Michael Tenis},
  journal = {Jounal of Energy},
  title   = {New article about something},
  year    = {2000},
  month   = aug,
  number  = {7},
  pages   = {66--88},
  volume  = {2},
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
For obtaining the same results (reference numerical sorting and author family name first) using `bibtex` and `natbib`, you may use the style `\bibliographystyle{acm}` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\usepackage[hidelinks, colorlinks=true]{hyperref} % OPTIONAL
%
\begin{document}
%
\section{Introduction}
In order to cite one reference, you can use cite command like this \cite{Doe_2020}. You can also cite two references like this \cite{Doe_2020,Tenis_2000}.
%
\bibliography{reference} % list of references is printed here
\end{document}
```

The output would be like

[image]

Comment: But this doesn't give such format 
Fan M, Vittal V, Heydt GT, Ayyanar R. Probabilistic power flow studies for transmission systems with photovoltaic generation using cumulants. IEEE Transactions on Power Systems 2012; 27 (4): 2251-2261.

Comment: Required such format at end 2012; 27 (4): 2251-2261.

Comment: Well I understand it's not exactly the format you wanted, it is the nearest to my knowledge however. As if you insist on the same exact format, you may need to manually edit the bibliography style files `*.bst` which I dont think you may like to do. Another solution is online looking for the style template of your desired bib format (it also ends with *.bst).

Comment: If you are willing to manually edit the `bst` style files, then start with your `unsrt` and then check this answer it may be useful to you https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168184/91556